# Touchpad acceleration in 23.04 is insane - possible to set it back to 22.10?

Tags: gnome, touchpad, 23.04

Touchpad acceleration in 23.04 is insane.
Any movement slightly faster than normal will jump to the edge of the screen.
Adjusting pointer speed does not help because then normal speed is too slow.

Vertical acceleration seems like it might be okay, but horizontal acceleration is insanely fast.

22.10 worked well, is there anyway to set it back to how it was in 22.10?

Using Ubuntu 23.04 Gnome Wayland

Comment: I'm not aware of any changes that would impact; but I'd firstly (*if this was a release-upgraded system*) boot with the 5.19 kernel (*assuming still on your system*) on your 23.04 or *lunar* system and see if that changes anything (ie. is it kernel/kernel.module or *driver* related).. If no change I'd go back to normal 6.2 kernel & .....   (ie. *ruling out different parts of stack*)

Comment: Using kernel 5.19 is better. Is there any way to fix this on 6.2+?